# Escape database object names

Tags: c#, sql-server, ado.net, sql-server-2016

I need to build a SQL Server 2016 script using string concatenation from within C# (the script will be executed via ADO.NET). I cannot use query parameters, which I would normally do, as the script is more of a setup script and contains non-parameterizable statements.

What's *the* way to go to escape names such that:

```
"ALTER DATABASE " + Escape(databaseName) + " ADD ..."
```

is not vulnerable to SQL injection? How to implement `Escape`? Currently I'm using square brackets around all names, however, that is not enough of course...

Comment: you could validate the variables checking for certain give aways like [ ] ; and " etc

Comment: @BugFinder, whilst ugly and wrong, and awful, and [insert more adjectives here], it's perfectly *legal* to have a table named `[` in SQL Server =(

Comment: true but you could make it a requirement for your app :) that you dont :D

Comment: Maybe it is okay to prevent such names - need to check with my product owner - is there a full list of "special characters" which would allow SQL injection?

Comment: @D.R., if you do go down the route of blacklisting/whitelisting, please go for whitelisting. It's safer if you've forgotten to add an allowed character to a whitelist than it is to forget to add a non-allowed character to a blacklist =)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use the [QUOTENAME](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/functions/quotename-transact-sql) SQL Server built-in function to achieve this.

As it looks very much like you're building up the script in C#, prior to executing it in SQL, you'll probably want to have a C# function that makes a trip down to the database to do this, perhaps also storing the resultant values in a `Dictionary<string, string>` to eliminate round-trips for strings that have already been quoted.

For example:

```
private Dictionary<string, string> _quotedNames = new Dictionary<string, string>();

private string GetSqlQuotedName(string name)
{
    if (!_quotedNames.ContainsKey(name))
    {
        _quotedNames[name] = GetSqlQuotedNameFromSqlServer(name);
    }

    return _quotedNames[name];
}

private string GetSqlQuotedNameFromSqlServer(string name)
{
    /// Code here to use your Data access method of choice to basically execute
    /// SELECT QUOTENAME(name) and return it
}
```

In fact, just to show this using the classes in the System.Data.SqlClient namespace, here's a class that performs this behaviour, when given a connection string to use to talk to SQL Server:

```
public class SqlNameEscaper
{
    private Dictionary<string, string> _quotedNames = new Dictionary<string, string>();
    private string _connectionString = string.Empty;

    public SqlNameEscaper(string connectionString)
    {
        _connectionString = connectionString;
    }

    public string GetSqlQuotedName(string name)
    {
        if (!_quotedNames.ContainsKey(name))
        {
            _quotedNames[name] = GetSqlQuotedNameFromSqlServer(name);
        }

        return _quotedNames[name];
    }

    private string GetSqlQuotedNameFromSqlServer(string name)
    {
        using (var connection = new SqlConnection(_connectionString))
        {
            connection.Open();
            using (var command = new SqlCommand("SELECT QUOTENAME(@name)", connection))
            {
                command.Parameters.AddWithValue("@name", name);
                var result = command.ExecuteScalar();

                return result.ToString();
            }
        }
    }
}
```

This can then be called by doing this:

```
var sne = new SqlNameEscaper(@"CONNECTION_STRING_HERE");
var bracket = sne.GetSqlQuotedName("[");
```

Or, in the context of your example:

```
var sqlNameEscaper = new SqlNameEscaper(@"CONNECTION_STRING_HERE");
var text = "ALTER DATABASE " + sqlNameEscaper.GetSqlQuotedName(databaseName) + " ADD ...";
```

There is also a question on dba.stackexchange.com that's worth having a read of on this very subject: [Should we still be using QUOTENAME to protect from injection attacks?](https://dba.stackexchange.com/q/136273/72163)

Comment: Is QUOTENAME also useable for "parameters", like in `ADD FILE (name = ' <in here>', ...)` ?

Comment: @D.R. - possibly, though you're more likely to start hitting the 128 character limit that the documentation mentions. If you're using the wrapper function(s) I've proposed above, then the resultant string can be used anywhere you want! =)

Answer (score 2):

If you are on regular .NET, use SqlCommandBuilder.QuoteIdentifier:

> Given an unquoted identifier in the correct catalog case, returns the correct quoted form of that identifier. This includes correctly escaping any embedded quotes in the identifier.

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.data.sqlclient.sqlcommandbuilder.quoteidentifier